# How to use EMBER.SORTABLEMIXIN?

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js, handlebars.js

My `FIXTURES` contains array of products which i want to sort based on ID.

```
Astcart.Application.FIXTURES=[
{
    "name" : "astr",
    "home_products": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Mobiles & Accessories"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Mobiles & Accessories"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mobiles & Accessories"
        }
    ]
}
];
```

I am not getting complete example of `EMBER.SORTABLEMIXIN`.I don't have any idea about sorting in ember.

Can anyone explain me how to do sorting in ember using my [this example(Not working)](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/degqH/2/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sortable feature is provided by [Ember.SortableMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html). This mixin expose two properties: `sortAscending` and `sortProperties`.

- The `sortAscending` accepts a boolean value determining if the sort is ascendant or not.
- And the `sortProperties` expect an array with the properties to sort.

For instance:

**Controller**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.SortableMixin, {
    sortAscending: false,
    sortProperties: ['id'],
});
```

These properties can be changed and the order will be updated, here is a sample with dynamic sort:

**Controller**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.SortableMixin, {
    sortProperties: ['firstName'], // or whatever property you want to initially sort the data by
    sortAscending: false, // defaults to "true"
    actions: {
        sortBy: function(property) {            
            this.set('sortProperties', [property]);
        }
    }
});
```

To access the arranged content, you should refer to `arrangedContent` in your template instead of the regular `model` property. Like this:

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h2>Index Content:</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th {{action "sortBy" "id"}}>ID</th>
        <th {{action "sortBy" "firstName"}}>First Name</th>
        <th {{action "sortBy" "lastName"}}>Last Name</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each arrangedContent as |prop|}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{prop.id}}</td>
          <td>{{prop.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{prop.lastName}}</td>
         </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>
```

You can see this working here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gunagoceyu/1/edit?html,js,output

I hope it helps

Comment: Can you help me to make my (http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/degqH/2/) this jsfiddle work?

Comment: What do you want to sort?

Comment: Here,i want to sort product based on its id.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ember.SortableMixin is going to be deprecated in Ember 2.0 (as well as the ArrayController), the recommended way to sort will be using `Ember.computed.sort()`, as illustrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31614050/525338